# Как в TabControl сделать контрол общим для всех страниц?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в TabControl сделать контрол общим для всех страниц?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианта два:

1. Иметь несколько копий контрола с общим источников данных. Т.о. с т.з. пользователя будет казаться, что это один и тот же контрол.
2. При переключении закладок динамически менять `Parent` у контрола, подставляя нужную страницу. Также нужно убедиться, что все размеры/относительные позиции контролов на всех страницах подходят для такого действия.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что можно 3. сделать absolute или relative позицию (style:position), и увеличив z-Index спозицировать елемент на нужное место.